# Android: Naming Resources

Tags: android, resources, naming-conventions

This is a question for Android developers but it is not a programming-related question as it affects nothing but the developer.

What conventions are the most commonly used when naming various resources like colors, drawables and strings and etc?

I have no doubts naming my layouts `activity_main` or `layout_secondary`. However, I have always doubts when naming resources mentioned previously. I never know whether I should name these resources after their use or the content. For example:

- Color: `dark_blue` vs `text_highlighted`
- Drawable: `blue_gradient` vs `top_bar_background`
- String: `welcome_to_app` vs `first_time_prompt`

Is there any community-created resource for good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming is pretty much personal preference. The name is perfect as long as the name indicates what the functionality of the defined thing is. Also you and any other developer using these definitions should know how what the names mean and which definition to choose. Quite easy if you are consistent with names throughout the project.

For example `dark_blue` is obviously a blue color while `text_highlighted` is the color of highlighted text. The name you should use depends on what you need: if you want to classify colors by their name take the first, if you like to abstract from the actual color take the second. For general layouts using `text_highlighted` will often make more sense since the actual color does not matter and the functionality (text highlight vs text regular etc.) is more important. In this example choosing between `text_highlighted` and `text_regular` is a lot more obvious than choosing between `color_light_blue` and `color_dark_blue` although they could refer to the same color. The name can help prevent errors.

Android uses prefixes for names in [`android.R.drawable`]
(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html) for example:

- `btn_` for button graphics
- `ic_` for icon graphics

  - `ic_menu_` for menu icons
  - `ic_dialog_` for dialog icons
- `stat_` for status icons

The schema is certainly not perfect but the advantage of using prefixes that start with the most generic classification is that you can use code completion to search for specific items step by step. So `color_blue_dark` could be better than `dark_blue_color`, at least if you consider the color classification more important than the dark / light classification. The same applies to `first_time_prompt`. If you have a lot of `prompt`s it would make sense to name them `prompt_first_time`, `promt_other_time`, ... If they can be classified by an activity for example that could be used as super category: `mainactivity_prompt_*`, `secondactivity_prompt_*` so you know where they belong to.

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK will be a good place to start for the good practices. You can open up any sample code in the SDK and go through the code and see the variable names.

Answer (score 1):

I usually name assets like colors and pictures for their content, but I will name a style or multiple state drawable for it's function.

for example:
`button_On.png; button_Off.png; button.xml`

That way if I want to use the same resource in multiple places it does not get confusing.
For example using a color as a text color in one style file and a background in another style file.

Comment: you cannot name resource file with uppercase letters.